# <p:dataTable> row selection

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Here's is the code i've got

```
<p:dataTable id="customerTable" var="customer" 
                             widgetVar="customerTableVar"
                             value="#{customerFacade.findAll()}"
                             selectionMode="single"
                             rowKey="#{customer.customerid}"
                             selection="#{editCustomerBean.customer}"
                             paginator="true" rows="10"  
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{customerBean.onRowSelect}"   
                            update=":form:growl" />
```

...

I want to display a command button when a row is selected.

here's my command button

I tried to modify `<p:ajax>` but nothing happened
here's my modified one

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{customerBean.onRowSelect}"   
                            update=":form:growl" oncomplete="editBut.show()"/>
```

can anyone point me out how to do it?

many thanks

Comment: And where is your button in your code?

Comment: Please include the code with the button and also your managed bean code

Comment: this is my command button

<p:commandButton widgetVar="editBut" icon="ui-icon-tag" value="Edit"
                                          oncomplete="editCustomerDlg.show()" 
                                         onsuccess="editCustomerDlg.hide()"/>

Comment: Customer bean

@Named(value = "customerBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean{
    private Customer customer;
    
    public CustomerBean() {
        customer = new Customer();
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Customer Selected", ((Customer) event.getObject()).getPhone());  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  


    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

}

Comment: Edit customerbean

    @Named(value = "editCustomerBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EditCustomerBean implements Serializable {

    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    
    public EditCustomerBean() {
    }
}

sry if there's a way to make codes more readable 
i'm new to this site